# Как получить содержимое мета-тега <title> по https адресу в Java?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Есть URL. Например:

```java
URL url = new URL("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/");
```

Нужно достать из страницы по этому адресу содержимое тега **title** из секции **head** и вернуть его.

Вот есть методы типа getHeaderFields() у URLConnection:

```java
System.out.println(url.openConnection().getHeaderFields());
```

Есть что-то такое, только по вытягиванию значения тега **title**?

В случае с адресом
`java URL url = new URL("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/");`  должно вернуться *"Stack Overflow на русском"*

Именно такое значение указано в секции head:

```html
<head>
<title>Stack Overflow на русском</title>
...
</head>
```

Comment: Пока так. Рабочий код, но не изящный.

```java
        URL url = new URL("https://ya.ru");
        BufferedReader pageContent = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())
        );

        String title = pageContent.lines()
                .filter(s -> s.contains("<title>"))
                .toList()
                .get(0)
                .split("<title>")[1]
                .split("</title>")[0];

        pageContent.lines().close();

        System.out.println(url + ": " + title);
```

Comment: Попробуйте для этой задачи использовать библиотеку jsoup.

Comment: Я для таких случаев использовал регулярку, но на самом деле куда не повернись, то нужно писать парсер.